# Strange behavior of match function in R

Tags: r, match

I'm trying to find out why the `match` function is showing strange behavior when comparing two numeric vectors. It obviously has something to do with the precision of the values, but I have been unable to find a good description of the issue. I have been able to solve the problem with `zapsmall` but wonder if there is a better way.

#### Example:

```
a <- seq(1,1.9,0.1)
a
# [1] 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9

b <- seq(0,1.9,0.1)
b
# [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9

match(a,b)
# [1] 11 12 NA 14 NA 16 17 18 19 20

match(zapsmall(a),zapsmall(b))
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Floating-point problem? Please have a look at:  `options(digits = 20); a[3] - b[13]`.  Then `a[1] - b[11]`.

Comment: Is there a way to approximate matching? (not exact) And how would it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that one possible solution is to use `pmatch` ("Partial String Matching"), although the functions first converts to a character vector with `as.character`. I'm sure there must be situations where this would cause problems, but it works for this case:

```
pmatch(a,b)
#[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that

```
a <- 10:19 / 10
a
# [1] 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9

b <- 0:19 / 10
b
# [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9

match(a,b)
#  [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

works well (without character conversion), so the problem might be "seq" rather than "match".